# Remove words from string if duplicated in a group of rows

Tags: r, lapply, gsub

I have a table that has at least two strings in the first cell that I need to select from and only retain one of them from a longer string.

```
  library(qdap)
  library(magrittr)
  t<-  read.table(text="
V1,V2
  Video of all presentations and discussionPart 1Part 2Video,Part 1
  Video of all presentations and discussionPart 1Part 2Video,Part 2
  Video of all presentations and discussionPart 1Part 2Video,Video
  Background - PDFVideo Soil management and update (pdf)Video,PDF
  Background - PDFVideo Soil management and update (pdf)Video,Video
  Background - PDFVideo Soil management and update (pdf)Video,Soil management and update (pdf)
  Background - PDFVideo Soil management and update (pdf)Video,Video
",
                  header=T,sep = ",")
```

So for this example I want to leave out "Part 2" from the first row of V1 and leave out "Part 1" from the second row of V1.

Here's what I tried:

```
t%>%  
  split(.,.$V1)%>% 
    lapply(.,function(x){(unique(x$V2))})%>%
      lapply(.,function(y){mgsub(pattern=y[[1]],replacement="",names(y))})
```

This attempt neither changes the longer string nor preserves the unique smaller strings.

The answer should look like this:

```
t<-  read.table(text="
V1,V2
Video of all presentations and discussionPart 1,Part 1
Video of all presentations and discussionPart 2,Part 2
Video of all presentations and discussionVideo,Video
Background - PDF,PDF
Background - Video,Video
Background - Soil management and update (pdf),Soil management and update (pdf)
Background - Video,Video
",
header=T,sep = ",")
```

Comment: Do the extra characters always come after the correct complete string?  Would you ever have 'Video of Animals-CricketsSirens'?

Comment: The extra characters do follow the string they go to, but those extra characters are not unique to each group. So I'd have examples like : 
'Video of Animals-ElephantCrickets,Elephant'
'Audio at loud volume-ElephantCrickets,Crickets'
'Audio at loud volume-ElephantCrickets,Elephant'

Comment: oops yep fixed it in the question too

Comment: Without clearer exclusion criteria, there's no good way to figure out what to exclude, as V2 only defines the target string you want to keep. Sometimes V2 occurs twice, and you want to keep both (e.g. "Video of all...Video"), but other times V2 occurs 2x and only want 1 (e.g. expected output for "PDFVideo...(pdf)Video" is "Video").  Maybe consider a "safe prefix" or "safe segments" column that identifies sections that never get excluded? Basically you need a procedure that encodes whatever boundaries/exceptions are known about the data. That part is hard for anyone else to help with.

Answer (score 1):

If everything before the "-" is always correct, and the only thing you want after the dash is the string in `V2`, then you can just grab the first part of the string and concatenate it to `V2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

t |> 
  mutate(str_segment = str_split(V1, "-", n = 2)) |> 
  unnest_wider(str_segment, names_sep = "_") |> 
  mutate(new_v1 = paste0(str_segment_1, "-", V2)) |> 
  select(new_v1, V2)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  new_v1                            V2      
  <chr>                             <chr>   
1 "  Video of Animals-Elephant"     Elephant
2 "  Video of Animals-Rhino"        Rhino   
3 "  Audio at loud volume-Sirens"   Sirens  
4 "  Audio at loud volume-Horns"    Horns   
5 "  Audio at loud volume-Crickets" Crickets
```

Alternately:

```
t |> 
  mutate(prefix = map(str_split(t$V1, "-", n=2), \(x) pluck(x, 1)),
         new_v1 = paste0(prefix, "-", V2)) |> 
  select(new_v1, V2)
```

Comment: This is simple. Do you have to `str_split` and `unnest`? I'd think you could just `mutate(V1new = mapply(sub, x = V1, pattern = "(-)[^-]*$", replace = paste0("-", V2)))`

Comment: My bad- there isn't always a dash "-" to do the str_split by FYI

Comment: @r2evans yes you're right, thanks for simplifying.

Comment: @CrunchTopping consider adding a bit in your post about what parts of the data are fixed/reliable and which parts are mutable.

Comment: ok just did thanks